# Проблема адаптивного дизайна

Tags: веб-дизайн, html, вёрстка

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, столкнулся с такой проблемой: при увеличении масштаба в браузере сайт переходит в адаптивный дизайн. Возможно ли избавится от этого?

**Обновление**

Сайт имеет адаптивный дизайн, который выполнен с помощью css.

Если заходить на сайт с мобильных устройств, то все отлично отображается, если заходить на сайт с персонального компьютера или ноутбука, то при увеличении масштаба он переходит в дизайн мобильной версии.

Вопрос в следующем: как сделать, чтобы на мобильных он был, а на стационарных нет?

**Обновление**

Выложил ксс, отвечающий за адаптацию, на jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sqk1exou/

Если убираю часть  с max-width, то адаптация не работает. Может, правильно её заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, уберите строки, которые делают дизайн адаптивным.

**Обновление:**

выложите css на jsfiddle или github, вероятно у вас там есть строки типа

```
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */   
}
```

Уберите часть с max-width.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нужен плагин определяющий мобильное ли это устройство (сделать это можно, например, с помощью Яндекс.Детектора. https://tech.yandex.ru/detector/) и уже в на настольном удалять стили, как писал выше автор:

> [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {/ *STYLES HERE* /}
> Уберите часть с max-width.

Но точно сказать не видя код не могу.